# Problem udating after just downloading 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

I have just recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 and when I run the updates for 12.04 and restart the computer, it goes to the purple loading page and freezes there. I have tried re-installing it several times and several different ways, but it continues to do it. If I do not install the updates it runs just fine and turns on. I think there is a problem with one of the updates. What can I do? Thanks!